# Stack Overflow dependence

Tags: discussion

It's very convenient to have such knowledge base as Stack Overflow that allows to use experience of thousands programmers all over the world. It is improved continuously and is started to be considered as routine tool.

But the morning sun never lasts a day. And the one thought about it bothers me. What if Stack Overflow falls once and is not restored? Are any guarantees of infinite maintain the subject? Or may be we could only rely on some out of date dump in that case and some clones?

Comment: Dependence? Don't worry, if SO falls you'll find me at the corner of the street ready to address your dependence needs. For a reasonable fee, of course.

Comment: I need jQuery @FrédéricHamidi. You have jQuery? Moar jQuery? Hit me up man. *rubs forearms*

Comment: @Bart, if have fresh 2.1.1, only 20% cut :) The bomb, baby!

Comment: Obligatory: http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data dumps are made on a regular basis and are available through https://archive.org/details/stackexchange. So even if SE falls, all data is not lost.

For some more relevant background information, [have a look at the relevant blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/).

Comment: But the data dumps don't give rep. :(

Comment: @Louis in the dump I downloaded I gave myself more rep than Skeet. And no bans so far.